# How can I print only every third index in Perl or Python?

Tags: python, arrays, perl

How can I do a for() or foreach() loop in Python and Perl, respectively, that only prints every third index? I need to move every third index to a new array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python

```
print list[::3] # print it
newlist = list[::3] # copy it
```

Perl

```
for ($i = 0; $i < @list; $i += 3) {
    print $list[$i]; # print it
    push @y, $list[$i]; # copy it
}
```

Answer (score 16):

**Perl:**

As with draegtun's answer, but using a count var:

```
my $i;
my @new = grep {not ++$i % 3} @list;
```

Comment: And can be nicely put in a do block:  my @new = do { my $i; grep {not ++$i % 3} @list };

Answer (score 9):

Perl 5.10 new [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) variables comes in very handy here:

```
my @every_third = grep { state $n = 0; ++$n % 3 == 0 } @list;
```

Also note you can provide a list of elements to slice:

```
my @every_third = @list[ 2, 5, 8 ];  # returns 3rd, 5th & 9th items in list
```

You can dynamically create this slice list using [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) (see Gugod's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464923/how-can-i-print-only-every-third-index-in-perl-or-python/1466696#1466696)) or a subroutine:

```
my @every_third = @list[ loop( start => 2, upto => $#list, by => 3  ) ];

sub loop {
    my ( %p ) = @_;
    my @list;

    for ( my $i = $p{start} || 0; $i <= $p{upto}; $i += $p{by} ) {
        push @list, $i;
    }

    return @list;
}
```

**Update:**

Regarding runrig's comment... this is "one way" to make it work within a loop:

```
my @every_third = sub { grep { state $n = 0; ++$n % 3 == 0 } @list }->();
```

Comment: state is nice. But if you execute that line more than once, it'll only work the first time unless the list length is a multiple of 3.

Comment: Well pointed out.  Its slightly annoying but not surprising feature of state variables which u can get around by encapsulating in an anonymous sub (see my update).

Comment: Why not do `map { $_ * 3 } 0 .. $MAX / 3` and use that for your slice index?

Comment: Indeed why not.  In fact I had already upvoted Gugod's answer on this ;-)   I didn't use map because there was already a similar answer here but for some reason it as now been deleted?

Answer (score 9):

Perl:

```
# The initial array
my @a = (1..100);

# Copy it, every 3rd elements
my @b = @a[ map { 3 * $_ } 0..$#a/3 ];

# Print it. space-delimited
$, = " ";
say @b;
```

Answer (score 8):

Python:

```
for x in a[::3]:
   something(x)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Python slices give me erections.

Answer (score 5):

You could do a slice in Perl.

```
my @in = ( 1..10 );

# need only 1/3 as many indexes.
my @index = 1..(@in/3);

# adjust the indexes.
$_ = 3 * $_ - 1 for @index;
# These would also work
# $_ *= 3, --$_ for @index;
# --($_ *= 3) for @index

my @out = @in[@index];
```

Answer (score 3):

In Perl:

```
$size = @array; 
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i+=3)  # or start from $i=2, depends what you mean by "every third index"
{  
        print "$array[$i] ";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@array = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9);
print @array[(grep { ($_ + 1) % 3 == 0 } (1..$#array))];
```